# jQuery identificando change do proprio jQuery

Tags: jquery

Quando click em "colocar", o campo é preenchido com a informação "mudou", mas, quando isso acontece, o Próximo `change` não identifica essa mudança.

**Na prática isso não funciona, como posso fazer isso funcionar?**

HTML

```
<button id="botao">Colocar</button>
<input id="campo">
```

jQuery

```
$('#botao').click(function(){
    $('#campo').val('mudou');
})

$('#campo').change(function() {
    alert('mudou mesmo');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLcap/2/

Comment: Quando você muda o valor programaticamente, o evento `change` não roda. E você está usando o seletor errado (`#input` em vez de `#campo`). Por que não fazer seja lá o que precisa logo após atribuir o valor?

Comment: Verdade cometi esse erro, mas mesmo colocando o nome correto `campo` O Problema ainda continar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como já mencionado, alterar o valor via Javascript não dispara o evento change.

Uma alternativa é executar o código desejado juntamente com a alteração do valor ao invés de confiar no evento.

Outra abordagem é executar manualmente o evento após a mudança usando o método `change()` ou `trigger("change")`.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#botao').click(function(){
    $('#campo').val('mudou');
    $('#campo').change(); // ou trigger("change")
})

$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('#campo').val('');
    $('#campo').change(); // ou trigger("change")
})

$('input').change(function() {
    alert('mudou mesmo');
});
```

Veja o jsfiddle [com `change()`](http://jsfiddle.net/KLMZ2/) ou [com `trigger()`](http://jsfiddle.net/gsn28/).

**Nota**: Cuidado ao invocar métodos que invocam eventos dentro de métodos que são chamados por eventos para não acabar em um loop infinito.

Answer (score 4):

O método `change` apenas ouve o evento `onchange` do browser, ele não é ativado quando o valor muda programaticamente. Uma alternativa seria você invocar o `change` manualmente através do comando `trigger`:

```
$('#botao').click(function(){
    $('#campo').val('mudou').trigger('change');
})

$('#campo').change(function() { // Nota: o id é "campo", não "input"
    alert('mudou mesmo');
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/yLcap/3/). Essa é uma dúvida comum, mas infelizmente não existe nenhum meio de se colocar um ouvinte que detecte mudanças à propriedade `value` do `input` feitas **programaticamente**. O mais próximo disso que pude encontrar é o `DOMAttrModified`, mas além dele não ser suportado pela maioria dos navegadores, ele [apenas é disparado em alterações nos atributos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418758/520779), e `value` é uma **propriedade**.

Answer (score 1):

Você não tem um `input` com o `id="input"`. Ou você corrige igual o @bfavaretto falou, ou no propio click do botão você pode chamar o alerta do input. Exemplo:

```
$('#botao').click(function(){
    $('#campo').val('mudou');
    if($('#campo').val()=='mudou') 
           alert('mudou mesmo');
})
```

Comment: Esse método precisa esta separado. Na minha situação atual.

Answer (score 0):

Formulário:

```
input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" value="1234"   
input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" value="" 
input type="submit" id="gravar" value="gravar alteracao"
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#campo').focus();  
   $('#gravar').css('display','none');  
   $('#campo').blur(function(){  
      $('this').val().trigger('change');  
   })  

   $('#campo').change(function() {   
      alert('o valor de campo foi alterado');  
      $('#gravar').css('display','block');  
   });  
});
```